# Complex Numbers - Finding Limits

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{z\to 1+i}\frac{z^4 + 2i}{iz-3}$$

Attempt:

I substituted $z = 1+i$ in the numerator and denominator:

Since $i^2 = -1$ I got $(1+i)^4 = -4$

So, $$\frac{-4 + 2i}{i-4}$$

Comment: Fine, though you will probably be expected to simplify your final answer.  Also, you should understand **why** this works: because numerator and denominator are continuous functions, and the denominator is not zero at the relevant point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but you may want to express your solutions as follows:
$$
\lim_{z\to i+1} \frac{z^4+2i}{iz-3}=\frac{(i+1)^4+2i}{i(i+1)-3}=\frac{-4+2i}{i-4}=\frac{18}{17}-\frac{4}{17}i.
$$
Of course, if this is homework, then you may want to spell out some of the details (e.g., how you came to the fact that $(i+1)^4=-4$, etc.).